# jQuery in Phonegap Login Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I'm making a login form for my Phonegap app, and am unable to send the user input to my server for validation.

Right now, I'm just trying to make sure the user input is being referenced in the first place, so I'm trying to `alert` it out.

When I do that, nothing happens.

But, if I comment out the hashing, everything works fine.

[Here's a link to the hashing script. It's worked before in other examples.](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/sha512.html)

Maybe I'm rusty with jQuery and missing something stupid, I don't know.

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#login").submit(function()
    {
        -- This block is what is commented or not to make the alert work --
        var NoHashPwd = $("#password").val();
        var HashedPwd = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd.value);
        $("#p").val(HashedPwd);
        password.value = "";
        -- End block --

        var uname = $("#uname").val();
        var p = $("#p").val();

        alert(uname);
    });
});
```

**LOGIN FORM**

```
<form id="login">
    <input type="hidden" name="login_lat" id="login_lat" value="fill" />
    <input type="hidden" name="login_lon" id="login_lon" value="fill" />
    <input type="hidden" name="p" id="p" value="coming" />

    <label for="uname">Username: </label>
    <input type="text" name="uname" id="uname" />
    <br />
    <label for="password">Password: </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: If the alert is not being triggerd this probably means your code is failing before that. Is there any exception showing in the javascript console?

I think NoHashPwd.value is wrong, since NoHashPwd will contain a string after getting the result of val().

Another option is that hex_sha512 is generating an exception inside.

Comment: @apanosa I added an answer where I figured it out thanks to you pointing out there may be an error with `NoHashPwd.value`

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it with the help of @apanosa

He was right about nothing being triggered and the `NoHashPwd.value` being incorrect.

By incorrect, I mean it was `NULL` and there was no value attached.

I changed my code to just make `NoHashPwd` a variable and referenced that in the `hash_sha512` function.

Thanks for the help @apanosa

**New JS**

```
var NoHashPwd = $("#password").val();
var HashedPwd = hex_sha512(NoHashPwd);
$("#p").val(HashedPwd);
$("#password").val(" ");

var uname = $("#uname").val();
var login_lat = $("#login_lat").val();
var login_lon = $("#login_lon").val();
var p = $("#p").val();
```